# Varnish multiple vcl wordpress and magento

Tags: varnish

I would like to configure my varnish server to have different .vcl configurations according to the hostname.
I have wordpress and magento in the same server apache+varnish 4.1.2

This is the default.vcl I tried to create, but I need to include a specific vcl for wordpress?

```
vcl 4.0;

# Default backend definition. Set this to point to your content server.
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8888";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    # Happens before we check if we have this in cache already.
    #
    # Typically you clean up the request here, removing cookies you don't need,
    # rewriting the request, etc.
if (! req.http.Host) { error 404 "Need a host header"; }
 set req.http.Host = regsub(req.http.Host, "^www\.", "");
 set req.http.Host = regsub(req.http.Host, ":80$", "");
if (req.http.Host == "hostname1.com") {  include "/etc/varnish/wordpress.vcl"; }
elsif (req.http.Host == "hostname2.com") {include "/etc/varnish/magento.vcl";}
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
}

sub vcl_deliver {

}
```

Comment: That should work? You've just got to be aware, the include will act just in the sub_recv section, not anywhere else. There's some examples with includes/vhosts here: 
https://info.varnish-software.com/blog/virtual-hosts-varnish

Comment: ok but what should I put in my wordpress.vcl?

Comment: The vcl to ensure WordPress is cached? There are plenty of guides available if you google them.

Comment: yes ok, but do I have to repeat the same vcl sintax as my default.vcl?   because I have tried already and I get errors

Comment: No, you need only the syntax for the WordPress site. Assume the code in WordPress.vcl is injected where you include it, and is executed there in the flow